# CSS Media Smartphones

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

Why do breakpoints like `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)` work for iphones and other modern smart phones even though they have for example **2436-by-1125-pixel** resolution?

When I am working with Dev Tools in Chrome, why does iPhone X show **812-by-375-pixel**? What am I missing or misunderstanding here?

Comment: The screen resolution and device width in pixels are different

Comment: https://juiceboxinteractive.com/blog/a-pixel-is-not-a-pixel-designing-for-a-new-generation-of-mobile-devices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Thank you for the answers.*

There are hardware pixels and software pixels. A hardware pixel is an individual dot of light in the display. A software pixel, also called a CSS pixel in the web world, is a unit of measurement.